# Как определить область выхода курсора за блок для выпадающего меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю мега меню на js , есть блок ( мега меню ) который появляться при наведение на пункт меню. Как сделать так , что бы блок ( мега меню ) исчезал не в момент ухода мыши с элемента меню , а именно с блока который был скрыт.

Спасибо.

```
<ul>
 <li id="menu-item-258">Link</li>
</ul>
<div id="mega-menu-box"> 
 <!-- Hidden content -->
</div>


jQuery(function($){
  $( "#menu-item-258" ).hover(
    function() {
      $('#mega-menu-box').css('opacity' , '1');
      $('#mega-menu-box').css('visibility' , 'visible');
      $('#mega-menu-box').addClass('opened-menu');
    } , function() {
      $('#mega-menu-box').css('opacity' , '0');
      $('#mega-menu-box').css('visibility' , 'hidden');
    }
  );
```

Comment: Добавьте свое мега меню в код иначе непонятно о чем идет речь

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин  добавил.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин http://sanahunt.site - тут наглядно

Comment: Во-прервых уберите второй function из hover, чтобы меню не пропадало, когда вы выходите курсором за его пределы. Далее добавьте отработку события курсора на элемент, который появляется.